# mysql error 1142 when installing owncloud

Tags: mysql, owncloud

I am installing ownCloud in a machine that is running Arch Linux and that has MariaDB, PHP and Apache up and running.
When I try to start ownCloud's installer, I get this error:

```
Error while trying to create admin user: An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE `oc_appconfig` (`appid` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `configkey` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `configvalue` LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX appconfig_config_key_index (`configkey`), PRIMARY KEY(`appid`, `configkey`)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB': SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 CREATE command denied to user 'owncloud'@'localhost' for table 'oc_appconfig'
```

It seems to be a problem of permissions. But I don't know why it is happening:

```
sql> USE owncloud;
sql> CREATE USER 'owncloud'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
sql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON owncloud TO 'owncloud'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If I check the privileges, they seem to be there:

```
sql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'owncloud'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for owncloud@localhost                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'owncloud'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****************************************' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `owncloud`.`owncloud` TO 'owncloud'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've tried dropping the user and creating it again, but I get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Try granting full permissions if you can and see if it works: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON star-dot-start TO 'owncloud'@'localhost'..you are right it has to be permissions!

Comment: It looks like it partially worked. Now I'm getting this: "Error while trying to create admin user: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'oc_user'@'localhost' to database 'owncloud'"

Comment: Assuming you have permissions to actually create the user you could try using "127.0.0.1" instead (or as well as) localhost - bit of a long shot that I think.  Instead confirm the user you are using to create the new user has the necessary permissions to do so.

Comment: The SHOW GRANTS is showing that the user does *not* have  privilege to create tables in the `owncloud` database.  To grant privileges on all objects in the database, use "on database dot star"  **`ON owncloud.*`**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend providing the mysql root user credentials. Given that, ownCloud should create its own user with restricted rights during setup.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution (which was found in a comment) worked for me:

> Assuming you have permissions to actually create the user you could try using "127.0.0.1" instead (or as well as) localhost - bit of a long shot that I think. Instead confirm the user you are using to create the new user has the necessary permissions to do so.
>
> – [@n34_panda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3459987/n34-panda) May 23 '14 at 9:09 ([original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23814287/#comment36655928_23814287))